# how to reinitialize Zend_Form_Element_Hash?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, csrf

On my web page I have `Zend_Form` with CSRF hash. It submits to the same page and it is used to update user's data (name, surname, birthdate and so on...). I would like to reinitialize CSRF hash after every valid post submission. How I could do it?

Now when I first time submit 'user data' form I get proper behavior (user data gets updated). But if I submit again (right after first, proper submit) to change another form field I get error saying:

> The two given tokens do not match

Is there anyway to reinitialize hash properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem came from tampering with Zend_Form_Element_Hash init methods, I had this:

```
$_csrf = new Zend_Form_Element_Hash($this->_csrfName);  
$_csrf->setSalt(md5($name));  
$_csrf->setAttrib('id', '');  
$_csrf->initCsrfToken();
```

The last line should never be there. When I removed it, everything started to act correctly.
@RockyFord: The `initCsrfToken()` function was place I was looking at the beginning, but
for me (I mean my intuition) it just couldn't be that. So I just debugged, debugged, debugged,
and at last commenting out 4th line was proper solution. Sorry for holding off reply, I totally forgot.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from this function in `Zend_Form_Element_Hash` the `$session->setExpirationHops` is set to **1 hop**, so if you try to resubmit the same form it will always fail. This is by design and is the root of the security you're seeking.

However you can change this behavior, simply extend `Zend_Form_Element_Hash` and override this method to set the *expirationHops* to a value you prefer  (*you can also set the session options manually at any time if you prefer*).

```
public function initCsrfToken()
    {
        $session = $this->getSession();
        $session->setExpirationHops(1, null, true);
        $session->setExpirationSeconds($this->getTimeout());
        $session->hash = $this->getHash();
    }
```

It goes without saying that it would be in the interest of security to perform a full refresh and repopulate the form to perform any edits. This should reset the hash.